# How to properly embed a html conditional code in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a situation and I am struggling to embed 2 conditional `html` code sequences inside of a `PHP` file. I was thinking, of using [include `PHP` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to call two separate external `html` files (`section1.html` and `section2.html`) in `header.php` like this:

```
                <!-- Start Header -->
                     ...                

                       <?php

                  /* a conditional PHP code is required in order to load 
                  the section1.html if the menu1** is shown on the page (?)*/    

                       include('section1.html');

                  /* also here, a conditional PHP code is required in order
                  to load the section2.html if the menu2** is shown on the
                  page (?)*/ 

                       include('section2.html');
                       ?>

                    ...

                <!-- End Header -->
```

Another approach using in between `PHP` tags:

```
                <!-- Start Header -->
                     ...                

                       <?php if(condition){ ?>
                          <!-- HTML code of section1 here -->
                  /*  above, a PHP (condition) that could load section1 if 
                  the menu1** is shown on the page, should be defined (?) */    
                       <?php } ?>


                       <?php if(condition){ ?>
                          <!-- HTML code of section2 here -->
                  /*  above a PHP (condition) that could load section2 if 
                  the menu2** is shown on the page, should be defined (?) */    
                       <?php } ?>


                     ...

                <!-- End Header -->
```

If this helps, I can expose the `html` code sections, but I think that at this point it's not so important.

**the conditional `PHP` code should be related to the above mentioned [menu1](http://goo.gl/iWDM9c) and [menu2](http://goo.gl/xGBMtI) made in wordpress/appearance/menus section.

LE:

HTML sections are,
section1:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
   ...
  </ul>
    <div id='menuRight'>
       <div>
           Home
           <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
       </div>
      <div>
          Portfolio
          <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
      <div>
          About
          <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and section2:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
    <div id='menuRight'>
       <div>
           Home
           <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
       </div>
      <div>
          Fiva
          <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
      <div>
          Caterham
          <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
      <div>
          Mobile
          <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any thoughts? Thank you,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It sounds like you've already answered yourself

Comment: I think OP is wondering about best practice?

Comment: hi, thank you for your interest. I need someone to compose the conditional `PHP` code ( at least in one of the above examples ) in order to work as follow: IF we are on [menu1](http://goo.gl/iWDM9c) page, `section1.html` file or section1 `html` code should be loaded; also if we are on [menu2](http://goo.gl/xGBMtI) page, `section2.html` or section2 `html` code, should be loaded.I've found these two solution but I have no idea how to implement these using conditional `PHP` code, that's why I need your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the menu1 and menu2 page links you included in your most recent comment, it looks like menu1 corresponds to your leaf pages and menu2 is your front page. If that's your intention then you could use the following conditional PHP.

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) : ?>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
        <div id='menuRight'>
            <div>
                Home
                <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                Portfolio
                <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                About
                <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<?php else : ?>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
        <div id='menuRight'>
            <div>
                Home
                <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                Fiva
                <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                Caterham
                <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                Mobile
                <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to include the code using external files you'd have to save them as .php files instead of .html. You can use the exact same code in those .php files, but it's important to use the .php extension when you save them. Here is what the files would look like:

**menu1.php**

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
        <div id='menuRight'>
            <div>
                Home
                <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                Fiva
                <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                Caterham
                <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                Mobile
                <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**menu2.php**

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
        <div id='menuRight'>
            <div>
                Home
                <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                Portfolio
                <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
            <div>
                About
                <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Then in your **header.php** file use this code:

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) : ?>
    <?php include 'menu2.php'; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php include 'menu1.php'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's important to make sure that the path to the **menu1.php** and **menu2.php** files are correct. My code above assumes that those two files are in the same directory as your header.php file.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!